# Creating and manipulating dataframes with only binary values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'s1':[1,2,3,4], 's2':[4,3,2,1], 's3':[7,4,3,1], 's4':[9,4,3,1]})
```

I want to do the following:

1. Map a predicate `>2` over `['s1', 's2']`, map a predicate `>4` over `['s3', 's4']` `if true set field to 1 else 0`.
2. Remove all rows where `s1 and s2 and s3 and s4 = 0`.
3. Group by permutations, for example how many rows are [0,1,1,0] etc
4. Query for different counts for example how many rows have `s3=1 or s2=1`?

The problem I'm having doing this on a larger dataset is that I have to split the dataset up into series and then iterate over each series and then put them back to a dataframe. I want to do all the transformatios and queries using only one pass over the data.

Update:
I have been trying something like this.

```
binary = pd.DataFrame({'s1':[1,0,1,0], 's2':[0,0,1,0], 's3':[1,0,1,1]})
```

2. `binary.loc[(cool!=0).any(axis=1)]`
3. `binary.groupby(['s1', 's2','s3']).count()` # it works for 2 values but not 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Items 1 and 2**

To map the predicate, use the `gt` function.  Then use `any` to select rows that have at least one `True` value (i.e. exclude rows that are all `False`).

You can use `astype(int)` when applying the predicate, but it doesn't seem necessary until after you filter for rows that are all `False`.

```
# Apply predicate.
df[['s1', 's2']] = df[['s1', 's2']].gt(2)
df[['s3', 's4']] = df[['s3', 's4']].gt(4)

# Remove rows that are all False and convert to 0/1.
df = df.loc[df.any(axis=1), :].astype(int)
```

The resulting binary DataFrame `df`:

```
   s1  s2  s3  s4
0   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   0   0
2   1   0   0   0
3   1   0   0   0
```

**Item 3**

To get a count of all row combinations at once, use `apply` to get a Series containing a `tuple` of each row, and use `value_counts`:

```
# Counts of permutations.
perms = df.apply(tuple, axis=1).value_counts()
```

The resulting output:

```
(1, 0, 0, 0)    2
(0, 1, 0, 0)    1
(0, 1, 1, 1)    1
```

**Item 4**

Sum over a Boolean array corresponding to your condition:

```
# Count of rows where s3=1 or s2=1.
row_count = ((df['s3'] == 1) | (df['s2'] == 1)).sum()
```

This yields `2` as expected.